# My try on this initial value problem: $\dot{x}=\sqrt{|{x}|}$, $x(0)=0$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'd like you to check if my try on this problem is correct. Here goes the statement:

> Given the initial value problem $\dot{x}=\sqrt{|{x}|}$, $x(0)=0$:
>
> $a)$ Give a solution to this IVP.
>
> $b)$ Is unique?
>
> $c)$ In case of a negative answer on $b)$, does this contradicts Picard's theorem of existence and uniqueness?

Ok, so here is my approach:

> $a)$ We see that the critical point is on $(0,0)$. I see two solutions to this problem:
>
> \begin{cases}-t^2/4\ \ \ \ if\ \ \  t<0 \\ t^2/4\ \ \ \ if\ \ \  t\geq0\end{cases}
>
> or
>
> \begin{cases}-t^2/4\ \ \ \ if\ \ \  t\leq0 \\ t^2/4\ \ \ \ if\ \ \  t>0.\end{cases}
>
> $b)$ Is unique? No, we have a problem on $(0,0)$, as I stated before.
>
> $c)$ Does this contradicts Picard's theorem? No, because $\sqrt{x}$ is not Lipschitz on $t=0$.

Is that correct?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Looks ok, other than it should be "$-t^2/4$ if $\color{red}{t < 0}$" etc. Another one to consider is $x(t) = 0$ for $t<0$ and $x(t) = t^2/4$ for $t>0$.

Comment: Thanks @Winther, didn't notice that before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both functions are identical as they have the same values everywhere, including at $t=0$. You get the additional solutions (with $a,b>0$, including one or both $\infty$)
$$
y(t)=
\begin{cases}
-\frac{(t+a)^2}4& \text{ for }&t\le -a
\\
0&\text{ for }&-a < t<b
\\
\frac{(t-b)^2}4 &\text{ for }&b \le t
\end{cases}
$$